# Can't access droppable() in Vue component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I'm having a little trouble here with using jQuery draggable/droppable within my view component `created()`.

If I use this within `<script>` it works perfectly, however once I've abstracted it out, `canvas.droppable()` is never called. I suspect this is ignorance to idioms on my part, but some help would be great!

Code:

```
Vue.component('design', {
props: ['user'],

/**
 * The component's data.
 */
data() {
    return {
        diagram: [
            {
                "_id": 1537472962719,
                "position": {
                    "top": 104,
                    "left": 407.29998779296875
                },
                "type": "TOOL-1"
            },
            {
                "_id": 1537473836985,
                "position": {
                    "top": 239,
                    "left": 643.2999877929688
                },
                "type": "TOOL-1"
            },
            {
                "_id": 1537473839676,
                "position": {
                    "top": 136.39999389648438,
                    "left": 228.29998779296875
                },
                "type": "TOOL-2"
            },
            {
                "_id": 1537473843399,
                "position": {
                    "top": 209.8000030517578,
                    "left": 422.29998779296875
                },
                "type": "TOOL-3"
            }
        ],
    };
},

/**
 * The component has been created by Vue.
 */
created() {
    let self = this;

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var canvas = $(".canvas");
        var tools = $(".tools");

        $(".tool").draggable({
            helper: "clone"
        });

        if (!self.diagram.length == 0) {
            renderDiagram(self.diagram);
        }

        canvas.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                console.log('dropped');
                var node = {
                    _id: (new Date).getTime(),
                    position: ui.helper.position()
                };

                node.position.left -= canvas.position().left;

                if (ui.helper.hasClass("tool-1")){
                    node.type = "TOOL-1";
                } else if (ui.helper.hasClass("tool-2")){
                    node.type = "TOOL-2";
                } else if (ui.helper.hasClass("tool-3")){
                    node.type = "TOOL-3";
                } else {
                    return;
                }

                self.diagram.push(node);

                renderDiagram(self.diagram);
            }
        });

        function renderDiagram(diagram) {
            canvas.empty();

            for (var d in diagram) {
                var node = diagram[d];
                var html = "";

                if (node.type === "TOOL-1") {
                    html = "<h3>TOOL 1</h3>";
                } else if (node.type === "TOOL-2") {
                    html = "<h3>TOOL 2</h3>";
                } else if (node.type === "TOOL-3") {
                    html = "<h3>TOOL 3</h3>";
                }

                var dom = $(html).css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": node.position.top,
                    "left": node.position.left
                }).draggable({
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var id = ui.helper.attr("id");

                        for (var i in diagram) {
                            if (diagram[i]._id == id) {
                                diagram[i].position.top = ui.position.top;
                                diagram[i].position.left = ui.position.left;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).attr("id", node._id);

                canvas.append(dom);
            }
        }
    });
},

    methods: {
        //
    }
});
```

For brevity; Imaging `diagram[]` is a dummy for data that will eventually be called from a database, grabbed by a Vue method. The elements within this array are drawn on the canvas on page load, and are able to be dragged, with their position updated within `daigram[]`, however trying to drag new items onto the canvas results in `droppable()` not being called, and thus the elements are not appended to the DOM.

Excuse my lack of experience with JS in general!

UPDATE:

Here's the blade template for reference

```
<design :user="user" inline-template>
    <div class="container-fluid"
         style="position: absolute;bottom: 0px;top: 0px;left: 0px;right: 0px;">
        <h1>Drag and Drop Tools Onto Canvas</h1>
        <div class="row"
             style="height: 100%;position: relative;">
            <div class="col-xs-3 tools"
                 style="background-color: #9acfea;position: absolute;top: 0px;bottom: 0px;left: 0px;">
                <h2>Tools</h2>
                <h3 class="tool tool-1">Tool 1</h3>
                <h3 class="tool tool-2">Tool 2</h3>
                <h3 class="tool tool-3">Tool 3</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 canvas"
                 style="background-color: beige;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</design>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working. It seems as though I wasn't reference the `diagram` variable correctly. This works:

```
Vue.component('design', {
props: ['user'],

/**
 * The component's data.
 */
data() {
    return {
        diagram: [],
    };
},

mounted() {
    // Get the canvas
    let self = this;
    var canvas = $(".canvas");
    var resource = $(".resource");

    // enable drag on the resources
    resource.draggable({
        helper: "clone"
    });

    // configure droppable on the canvas
    canvas.droppable({
        // define allowed elements
        accept: resource,

        // configure the drop event
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            // create object for dropped element
            var node = {
                _id: (new Date).getTime(),
                position: ui.helper.position(),
            };

            // repaint left due to sidebar position
            node.position.left -= canvas.position().left;

            // Append type to object
            if (ui.helper.hasClass("test")) {
                node.type = "test";
            }
                return;
            }

            // push the element onto the diagram array
            self.diagram.push(node);
            render();
        }
    });

    // Define the render function to add resources to the diagram
    function render() {
        // Here we empty the canvas so we can re-draw it
        canvas.empty();

        // Traverse the resource array and action
        self.diagram.forEach(r => {
            // Grab the individal node
            var node = r;

            // Creat empty html variable
            var html = "";

            // Here we generate our html for when the element has been dropped
            if (node.type === 'test') {
                html = "<h3>Test</h3>"
            }

            // Generate the css for the dom element
            var dom = $(html).css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": node.position.top,
                "left": node.position.left
            })
                // Configure draggable of dropped items
                .draggable({
                    stop: function(event, ui) {
                        var id = ui.helper.attr("id");

                        for (var i in self.diagram) {
                            if (self.diagram[i]._id == id) {
                                self.diagram[i].position.top = ui.position.top;
                                self.diagram[i].position.left = ui.position.left;
                            }
                        }

                        // render();
                    }
            }).attr("id", node._id);

            // Append the dom element to the canvas
            canvas.append(dom);
        })
    }
}
});
```

Also, as an added note here: I was noticing poor performance with the drag and drop. Disabling the transitions as follows fixed this:

```
ul.projects li:not(.ui-sortable-helper) {
   float: left;
   margin: 0px 6.5px 12px;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
   transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
```

Finally, here is the HTML I'm working with (bootstrap 4):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100vh;">
        <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <h3 class="test resource">AWS Instance</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="canvas col-md-9">
                {{--Things here--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```